# Hudson is giving error while creating the test report

Tags: hudson, mxunit

I am getting the follwoing error from Hudson. Could any one please tell me what is wrong here. My test cases are working fine.

```
Total time: 0 seconds
Recording test results
```

> ERROR: Failed to archive test reports
>   hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed: C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\hudson\workspace\xxx at hudson.remoting.Channel@5ad977d6:NodeA
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:754)
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser.parse(JUnitParser.java:83)
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.parse(JUnitResultArchiver.java:132)
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.perform(JUnitResultArchiver.java:144)
>       at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:630)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:608)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:584)
>       at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:159)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:553)
>       at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1390)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
>   Caused by: hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to read C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\hudson\workspace\xxx\xxx\testresults\testresults.properties
>   Is this really a JUnit report file? Your configuration must be matching too many files
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:205)
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:155)
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.(TestResult.java:118)
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:114)
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:87)
>       at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:1960)
>       at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:114)
>       at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
>       at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:283)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:60)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document file:///C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/hudson/workspace/xxx/xxx/testresults/testresults.properties : Content is not allowed in prolog. Nested exception: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>       at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
>       at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:264)
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.SuiteResult.parse(SuiteResult.java:98)
>       at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:199)
>       ... 15 more
>   Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/hudson/workspace/xxx/xxx/testresults/testresults.properties; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
>       ... 18 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because HUDSON is trying to parse your test results in file testresults.properties. It is getting a SAXParseException because testresults.properties does not contain valid XML. This is probably because you have no tests in your project.

Answer (score 0):

OR because you have both HTMLs and XMLs (like I did). Make sure you only include *.xml.